# Remove string before and after given string paragraph in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a sample paragraph here:

```
var story = "Once upon a time, there was a little girl named <i>Goldilocks.</i>
She went for a walk in the forest. Pretty soon, she came upon a house. <strong>She 
knocked and, when no one answered, </strong>she walked right in. At the table in the kitchen, 
there were three bowls of porridge. Goldilocks was hungry. She tasted the porridge from the first bowl.";
```

What I want to do is to trim or remove certain paragraph before and after a certain selected characters. This certain paragraph is after the `</i>` and before the `<strong>` html tag. So far, I tried using the `Substring`

```
story.Substring(story.IndexOf("<strong>"));
```

But it removes everything before the `<strong>` What I want to achieve for the result is something like this:

```
var story = "Once upon a time, there was a little girl named <i>Goldilocks.</i><strong>She 
knocked and, when no one answered, </strong>she walked right in. At the table in the kitchen, 
there were three bowls of porridge. Goldilocks was hungry. She tasted the porridge from the first bowl.";
```

Without the `She went for a walk in the forest. Pretty soon, she came upon a house.`

I also tried this,

```
story = story.Substring(story.IndexOf("</i>")).Substring(0, story.LastIndexOf("<strong>" + 1);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to achieve your group and do advanced replacement.
Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(story, "</i>.*?<strong>", "</i><strong>");
```